# código fonte de cabeça pra baixo

Tags: sublime-text

Alguém sabe como resolve? Eu uso sublime text ele ficou assim do nada.

[image]

Comment: Isso acontece sempre que abre o software? Já verificou os plugins instalados? Isso aconteceu depois de alguma modificação?

Comment: Veja se existe a opção Edit > Permute Lines > Reverse

Comment: Esse procedimento resolveu meu problema em partes, porém o código apareceu embaralhado mas mesmo assim, muito obrigado. Foi a primeira vez que isso aconteceu comigo! Não tenho plugin instalado.